# How do I use calc() with min-content?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I have a grid layout which can be simplified like this.

What I want to achieve is the `.side` should take whatever space the content needs to by default using `min-content`, but user can enlarge it by increasing the `--size` custom css property.

I tried `calc(min-content + var(--size))` but it doesn't work. I can't assign a specific value like `calc(100px + var(--size))` since the original size should be determined by its content.

What is the best approach to achieve such a feature?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  --size: 10px;

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "l t"
    "l b";
  
  /* doesn't work */
  /* grid-template-columns: calc(min-content + var(--size)) 1fr; */
  
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container > * {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.side {
  grid-area: l;
}

.top {
  grid-area: t;
}

.bottom {
  grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="side">This should have a 10px gutter on the right</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use padding. Then add it to the side you choose

Comment: @a.mola Because the content can not be inside of the padding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `width:calc(100% + var(--size))` for the grid item. This will create an overflow that you can rectify by adding a gap:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  --size: 20px;

  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "l t"
    "l b";
  
  /* doesn't work */
  /* grid-template-columns: calc(min-content + var(--size)) 1fr; */
  
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap:var(--size);
}

.container > * {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.side {
  grid-area: l;
  width:calc(100% + var(--size));
}

.top {
  grid-area: t;
}

.bottom {
  grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="side">This should have a 10px gutter on the right</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ah I see, that is quite clever, thanks very much!